# Java - Open data URI with browser

Tags: java, browser, awt, data-uri, data-uri-scheme

I'm generating an HTML file than I want to open with a browser. The thing is I am generating the the markup in memory and am converting it to a data URI. Copy pasting the data URI into the browser's address bar works correctly but when trying to open the same URI using:

```
String encoded = "data:text/html;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(htmlString.getBytes());

if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(encoded));
}
```

The popup does not allow me to choose a web browser (maybe because it doesn't recognize the data uri format).

How do I open a browser window using a data URI?

Edit: Added more code

[Sample Data URI](https://paste.ee/p/MJOrM)

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: added some more code